# Weierstrass M test from series to sequence

Tags: real-analysis

One of the questions we were given in my class is:

The Weierstrass M-Test is a test for uniform convergence of a series of functions.  By converting a sequence of functions into a series (by the telescoping trick), see if you can formulate a theorem (i.e., a ``test'') for uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

I am having trouble understanding how I should be doing this. I know I should use something like $a_n(x) = \sum^N(a_n(x) - a_{n-1}(x)) = a_N(x) - a_0(x)$ from the comment on the telescoping trick, but otherwise I'm lost. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: If $\lvert a_n(x) - a_{n-1}(x)\rvert \leqslant M_n$ for all $x$ and $n$, and $\sum M_n$ ...